# Add Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, razor-pages-crud

I used the add *Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)* option. It creates several pages to create, delete, etc. a selected Entity Framework model.

I then used the same command to create pages for another Entity Framework model. And now I get a bunch of build errors because the class names used the first time (`CreateModel`, `DeleteModel`, `DetailsModel`, etc.) are always the same. So now I have multiple definitions for each class.

This seems like a major weakness if non-unique class names are used. The feature can only be used once per project. Shouldn't the class names include the Entity Framework model name or something so that they are unique?

Comment: Could you show the steps to reprodcue your problem and show the error message please?Do you create new folders for each entity like Students,Teachers in `Pages` folder and right click the folder to do the scaffolding for specific entity?Those razor Pages will have different namespaces (`MyApp.Pages.Departments` and `MyApp.Pages.Students`) which will not cause the conflict.

Comment: @XingZou: The error I get is the standard error you get when you define the same class more than once. I used a different folder each time I ran the command. Creating different namespaces for each folder is probably the correct fix to this issue. I have reported the issue to Microsoft and I will probably delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft, this is a bug introduced in Visual Studio 16.4 and is fixed for 16.5 (see [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/866577/razor-pages-using-entity-framework-crud-class-name.html)).

The fix changes the name of each namespace to reflect the folder name. So there is no conflict as long as each CRUD scaffolding occurs in a different folder.